# Converting dictionary key datatype

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I've seen some questions asked but they change both value and keys.

I have the glove embedding dictionary that's in public access. It has words as the keys and 300 values for each key. The keys are `str` datatype and the values are `float`.

I need to change the keys to `'numpy.unicode_'` data type. But just the keys. How do I go about doing that?

My current dictionary looks like this:

`'king' : [0.0033901, -0.34614, 0.28144, ...]`

These float values are to be unchanged, it is a 300 dimensional embedding. I just need to change the datatype of the key, 'king' in the example I've given to numpy unicode

I tried this from another solution I found:

`unidict = {key.decode('utf8') for key in embedding_dict()}`

But it gives the error "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"

Comment: Can you please give the input and the expected output? As examples I mean, not onyl descriptions, as being acurate with descriptions and leaving no room for asumption is quite hard.

Comment: I want to but its too big, haha.

see this is what it looks like now:

Comment: I've made the edit. As you can see its huge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
unidict = {key.decode('utf8'): value for key, value in embedding_dict.items()}
```

or:

```
unidict = {key.decode('utf8'): embedding_dict[key] for key in embedding_dict}
```

The first one is prefered.

In your example (after deleting the parenthesis after `embedding_dict`) you are creating a `set` with the keys from the dict, not a `dict`.

Comment: right, I am creating a set. That wasn't what I was supposed to do. I apologise for the poor framing of the question. How do I update the original `dict` with the unicode keys?

Comment: @ArjunMohan Use the above code, just replace `embedding_dict` with your original dict and `unidict` with the name of the variable you want to use for the updated one. You could even use the same variable overwriting its content. It will create a new `dict` in memory either way but the inner `list`s wont be created in memory again, just assigned to the new one.

Comment: i did just that, and while it did get converted to unicode, it's apparently not the same as `numpy.unicode_`

Comment: I basically have an equality operator with another dictionary.
The other dictionary keys have the type `numpy.unicode_`
so when the equality operator comes into play, it gives the error:
"UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal"

Comment: @ArjunMohan Oh, your problem comes when comparing `str`s or `unicode`s to `np.unicode_`. Python version?

Comment: initially it was `str` to `np.unicode_` but I managed to change all the `str` to `unicode` so now its `unicode` not matching with `np.unicode_`

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: yeah I checked the individual values. It says error but it's just a warning I think because the mapping that I needed worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `error` in:

```
unidict = {key.decode('utf8') for key in embedding_dict()}
```

is that you are trying to `call` `embedding_dict`. Try instead, just:

```
unidict = {key.decode('utf8') for key in embedding_dict}
```

Comment: yep, this worked. How do I now replace the keys in my dictionary `embedding_dict` with the unicode keys in `unidict`?

Comment: @ArjunMohan Well, as `unidict` is created from `embedding_dict`, don't bother creating `unidict` and just reassign straight to `embedding_dict` so: `emdedding_dict= {key.decode('utf8') for key in embedding_dict}`. Hope this helps! Also, please up-vote the answer if it was useful to you...Thank you **:)**

Comment: I did, but my reputation isn't apparently high enough for it to be visible lul

In any case, unicode doesn't work because the words in the dictionary I'm comparing it to are of the type `numpy.unicode_` 

it gives the error "UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal" due to this. I think I'll try changing the source encoding to utf-8 from the start itself.

Comment: @ArjunMohan yes that sounds like the best solution... good luck!